# How to concatenate multiple rows in one column based on data in another column in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Okay so I have a dataframe that has one column of characters spread out over several rows. It's not consistent as some are spread out over three rows and others over four. There's also inconsistent space between each grouping.  I want to concatenate these rows so they're in one cell based on data in another column. The df looks something like this:

```
    Name       Location
[1]  Mr.       NE
[2]  Thomas
[3]  Smith
[4]
[5]  Mrs.      NW
[6]  Carrie
[7]  Ann
[8]  Brown
[9]  Elizabeth SE
[10] Johnson
```

I want to get it to something like this:

```
    Name                  Location
[1] Mr. Thomas Smith      NE
[2] Mr. Thomas Smith 
[3] Mr. Thomas Smith 
[4] Mr. Thomas Smith 
[5] Mrs. Carrie Ann Brown NW
[6] Mrs. Carrie Ann Brown
[7] Mrs. Carrie Ann Brown
[8] Mrs. Carrie Ann Brown
[9] Elizabeth Johnson     SE
[10]Elizabeth Johnson
```

I'd like to keep the extra rows in between as there's other data that's stored in them in other columns. I want to concatenate the name column based on its relation to the location column. The only pattern I've been able to find in the name column is that each set of rows that needs to be merged starts on the same row as the data in location column and end before the next location.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can share code that produces the data, rather than a printout of what the data looks like. R allows various data types and structures which may print out identically. `dput(head(df, 10))` should produce code for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea. I created a group variable first. For each group, I concatenated strings. I removed white space with trimws(). For Location, I took the first element in each group and used it to fill all empty spots. If necessary, you want to remove the grouping variable in the output.

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(mydf,
         group = cumsum(nchar(Location) > 0)) %>%
mutate(Name = trimws(paste(Name, collapse = " ")),
       Location = first(Location)) 

   Name                  Location group
   <chr>                 <chr>    <int>
 1 Mr. Thomas Smith      NE           1
 2 Mr. Thomas Smith      NE           1
 3 Mr. Thomas Smith      NE           1
 4 Mr. Thomas Smith      NE           1
 5 Mrs. Carrie Ann Brown NW           2
 6 Mrs. Carrie Ann Brown NW           2
 7 Mrs. Carrie Ann Brown NW           2
 8 Mrs. Carrie Ann Brown NW           2
 9 Elizabeth SE Johnson  SE           3
10 Elizabeth SE Johnson  SE           3
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(Name = c("Mr.", "Thomas", "Smith", "", "Mrs.", 
"Carrie", "Ann", "Brown", "Elizabeth SE", "Johnson"), Location = c("NE", 
"", "", "", "NW", "", "", "", "SE", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```